# Displaying TextView value in fragment.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, textview

I am just starting to build my first application.

I received the user input from one activity and passed this value to my new activity.
From here, I set up new TextView like this:

```
Intent parentintent = getIntent();
Bundle dimval = parentintent.getExtras(); 
String width = (String) dimval.get("widthValue");   
String length = (String) dimval.get("lengthValue");
TextView widthView = new TextView(this);
TextView lengthView = new TextView(this);
widthView.setText(width);
lengthView.setText(length);
```

From here, I am stuck on how to use these TextViews (widthView and lengthView) in fragment_xxxx.xml file to actually display these string values. Could someone please help me out with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add them to something. But you really should use XML layouts, they are easier. For example, here's one in my newest project:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kd7uiy.qslmapper.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The text is as simple as adding an `android:text` to the `TextView` tag. Show it with the `setContentView(R.layout.layout_name)`. Get a reference by `findViewById(R.id.section_label)`

If you insist on manually putting it together, you have to add it to a `ViewGroup`, then set the content view as that. Something like this could work:

```
LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);
layout.add(widthView);
layout.add(lengthView);
setContentView(layout);
```

This would change if done in a fragment, it would instead be the returned value of the `onCreateView()` function (Same until setContentView, then return layout)

Comment: Yes I'm trying to do this is XML layouts as well, but I do not know how to reference that specific TextView in android:text .. could you help? Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry I'm very new at this so I'm not completely understanding it.. so do I reference it like android:text=findViewById(R.id.section_label) ?
This just diplays "findView..." on the screen. I think I'm misunderstanding something really badly :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created the TextView  in the xml layout then you don't need to instantiate them with the new`TextView() instead use:

```
TextView widthView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_width);
widthView.setText(width);
```

assuming `text_width` is the name of the android id for your TextView`